# How do you add inputs to dictionaries and set a default value for new inputs

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, I'm trying to answer a question in a challenge

question:
**You're spending a day at Funland Carnival with friends. You've decided to see who can win the most slinkies from carnival games!
Slinkies cost tickets which you can win from playing games. Write a program that tracks everyone's tickets as they play games.
Ask for friend's names and how many tickets they're starting with until a blank name is entered. Print how many slinkies they can buy with their starting amount.
We've started a buy_slinkies function for you. Each slinky costs 3 tickets, but you can only buy a whole number of slinkies. This means you'll need to round down.**

Code:

```
def buy_slinkies(tickets):
  # Finish the function to convert tickets to slinkies
  return  tickets / 3

# Write the rest of your program here

players = {}

print("Who's here at the carnival today?")
friends = input('Name: ')
while friends:
  
  starting = int(input('Starting tickets: '))
  players[friends] = starting
  slinkies = buy_slinkies(starting)
  final_tickets = int(slinkies)
  start = print(f"{friends}'s here, starting with {final_tickets} slinkies worth of tickets!")
  friends = input('Name: ')
  
print('Let the games begin!')

current_player = input('Who played? ')
while current_player:
  tickets = input('Tickets won/lost: ')
  current_player = input('Who played? ')


print("End of the day! Let's see how everyone did!")

for human, notickets in players.items():
  noslinkies = buy_slinkies(notickets)
  final_slinkies = int(noslinkies)
  print(f"{human} can buy {final_slinkies} slinkies.")
```

This is how mine looks:
[image: The final value is the same as the starting value (It does not update the dictionary)]

This is how the output should look:
[image: The final value is updated in the dictionary]

Comment: What's the question here? If you want to change the number of tickets, it's `player[current_player] += int(tickets)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This block of code is where you will want to update the ticket count.

```
current_player = input('Who played? ')
while current_player:
  tickets = input('Tickets won/lost: ')
  current_player = input('Who played? ')
```

To update it first you will want to find the player name entered.

```
if current_player in players:
```

If the player is found then you can add/substract their ticket count.

```
if current_player in players:
  players[current_player] += int(tickets)
```

If they are not found you can add them to the dictionary and initialize their key/value with the default ticket count. But you did not specify what the default should be so I am going to assume it's whatever is specified in the input.

```
else:
  players[current_player] = int(tickets)
```

Complete code is below

```
def buy_slinkies(tickets):
  # Finish the function to convert tickets to slinkies
  return  tickets / 3

# Write the rest of your program here

players = {}

print("Who's here at the carnival today?")
friends = input('Name: ')
while friends:
  
  starting = int(input('Starting tickets: '))
  players[friends] = starting
  slinkies = buy_slinkies(starting)
  final_tickets = int(slinkies)
  start = print(f"{friends}'s here, starting with {final_tickets} slinkies worth of tickets!")
  friends = input('Name: ')
  
print('Let the games begin!')

current_player = input('Who played? ')
while current_player:
  tickets = input('Tickets won/lost: ')
  if current_player in players:
    players[current_player] += int(tickets)
  else:
    players[current_player] = int(tickets)
  current_player = input('Who played? ')


print("End of the day! Let's see how everyone did!")

for human, notickets in players.items():
  noslinkies = buy_slinkies(notickets)
  final_slinkies = int(noslinkies)
  print(f"{human} can buy {final_slinkies} slinkies.")
```